# Validate form fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

folks.

I hope you don't see this as a silly question because i am new to JavaScript. I did my research on how to solve this problem but the answers i found on stack overflow were kind of too high for me right now. And i don't like to copy codes either. I want to learn it. My JavaScript code worked on one field but didn't work for all fields even when i did a loop.

Please you are free to show me how to do this professionally. I would be grateful to see many approaches or methods. Gracias

---

```js
function Validate(x){
    var required = document.getElementsByClassName("required");
    for(var x = 0; x > required.length; x++){
    if ((required[x].value == "") || (required[x].value == null)) {
        required[x].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        required[x].style.color = "white";
    } else {
        required[x].style.backgroundColor = "";
        required[x].style.color = "#777";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<p>
 <label for="textfield">Name</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="forme required"  onblur="Validate(name)"  />
   <br />

  <label for="textfield">Surname</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" class="forme required" />
   <br />

  <label for="textfield"> School</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="school" id="school" class="forme required" />
   <br />

  <label for="textfield">Mobile</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="forme required" />
   <br />

  <label for="email"> Email</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="forme required"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="Validate()" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
```

---

Be grateful for ya time.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/rickharrison/validate.js/

Comment: `x > required.length` should be `x < required.length`

Comment: What is the real problem, like are you getting some errors or the output is not as expected? Knowing this will be more helpful for us to help. Thanks

Comment: It just work. The form just stood there like dead. It didn't respond at all. No error, nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments of your question, you used the wrong sign (">" ist false, "<" is true). But your code has some more failures.

- The `for` attribute on the `label` elements should always point to the respective input field, so use the ID of the input field.
- It's may better to use the JavaScript `addEventListener` method instead of the DHTML attribute `onclick`, but that is probably a matter of taste.

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var req     = document.querySelectorAll("form input.required"),
        error   = false;
        
    for(var i = 0; i < req.length; i++){
        if(req[i].value.trim() == ""){
            if(!error){
                error = true;
            }
            req[i].style.setProperty("color", "#ffffff");
            req[i].style.setProperty("background-color", "#ff0000");
        } else {
            req[i].style.removeProperty("color");
            req[i].style.removeProperty("background-color");
        }
    }
    
    if(error){
        // Prevent Form Submit
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="forme required" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="surname">Surame</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" class="forme required" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="school"> School</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="school" name="school" class="forme required" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="mobile">Mobile</label><br />
        <input type="tel" id="mobile" name="mobile" class="forme required" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="email"> Email</label><br />
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="forme required" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Please note: Don't use ONLY JavaScript to validate your form fields. You should always check the passed user informations on the server side too, because you can't control the user.

Have fun learning JavaScript.

Sincerely,
Sam.

Comment: Thank you plenty Sam. I did validate my submission with php. But I need JavaScript. Thanks for you response. I will deploy it immediately. But I have one issue. Can you please explain:  1. Line 1 -  you have 2 event listeners. I don't understand why you did that. 2. What is the function of adding error = false. 3. What is req[i].value.trim(). What does this trim() function do?

Comment: Hello, no problem. 

1. Line 1 has just a single addEventListener, which is "hooked" on the Button with the id "submit" `document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event){` 

2. The error variable controls the `event.preventDefault();` function. So if the function encounters an error (an empty field), it will set the error variable to true and prevent the submit of the form (`event.preventDefault();`). If no error: Form get submit and send to PHP.

3. `trim()` just removes any empty Space of a string. It turns "     abc       " into "abc".

Sincerely, Sam.